# Magento 2: How to get file size in folder to check size?

Tags: magento2

i try get_headers function of php but how can get size by path file in magento 2?

```php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

print_r(get_headers($url));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a directory path of the file along with below function of PHP.

```
$file = '/path/to/your/file';
$filesize = filesize($file);
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much <3